# Dynamically disable form in form events symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have many entities, each of which has its own form type. Some of the entities implements `FooBarInterface` comprising method `FooBarInterface::isEnabled();`

I want to create a Form Extension, to be check data_class at all forms, and disable form if entity implements `FooBarInterface` and `entity::isEnabled()` return false.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class MyExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $dataClass = $builder->getDataClass();
        if ($dataClass) {
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($dataClass);

            if ($reflection->implementsInterface(FooBarInterface::class)) {
                $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $formEvent) {
                    $data = $formEvent->getData(); 
                    if ($data && !$data->isEnabled()) {
                        // todo this need disable all form with subforms
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

I have to make it through the `$ builder-> addEventListener`, because `$ builder-> getData ()` do not always have the time to create a form. But after the creation of the form, I can not change her option disabled

How do I change the option disabled in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Form Extension with method

```
    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) 
    {
        $dataClass = $form->getConfig()->getDataClass();
        if ($dataClass) {
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($dataClass);

            if ($reflection->implementsInterface(FooBarInterface::class)) {
                /** @var FooBarInterface$data */
                $data = $form->getData();

                if ($data && !$data ->isEnabled()) {
                   $this->recursiveDisableForm($view);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function recursiveDisableForm(FormView $view) 
    {
        $view->vars['disabled'] = true;
        foreach ($view->children as $childView) {
            $this->recursiveDisableForm($childView);
        }
    }
```

For disable changes if data is submitted I create Doctrine Event Subscriber with `FormEvents::PRE_UPDATE` event:

```
    /**
     * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $args
     */
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof DataStateInterface) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$entity->isEnabled()) {
            $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->clearEntityChangeSet(spl_object_hash($entity));
        }
    }
```